# My switch statement or the document.write(); isn't working and i can't fix it

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Hello I want to display a specific text each day and I don't know where is the problem in the following code, I am using jQuery mobile and I thought that javascript is the one that can do this on a web page.

```
<div data-role="content">
            <div>
            <script>
                var n = new Date().getDay();
                var ch = new String();



                switch(n)
                {
                    case 0:
                    {
                    ch = String("\“It is not so easy to leave your comfort zone, it is a very difficult thing to do, 
                    but it most certainly will change your future and make you a better person than you ever could imagine\”<br><br>Today\'s challenge:<br><br>
                    Do you live in the future?<br><br>
                    Become aware of moments when you are lost in thinking about the future, whether it is 10 minutes or 2 years from now. 
                    Notice how it pulls your attention from the present moment. See the reasons why you are running from your current experience.<br>");

                    }
                    break;

                    case 1:
                    ch = String("A dream is your creative vision for your life in the future. You must break out of your current comfort zone and become comfortable with the unfamiliar and the unknown.-Denis Waitley<br><br>
                    Today\'s challenge(Do one of them, or more if you like so...):<br><br>
                    Do everyday things differently. 
                    Take a different route to work. 
                    Try a new restaurant without checking Yelp first. Go vegetarian for a week, or a month. 
                    Try a new operating system. Recalibrate your reality. 
                    Whether the change you make is large or small, make a change in the way you do things on a day-to-day basis. 
                    Look for the perspective that comes from any change, even if it\'s negative. 
                    Don\'t be put off if things don\'t work out the way you planned.");
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    ch = String("Life begins at the end of your comfort zone. -Neale Donald Walsch<br<br>
                    Today\'s challenge:<br><br>
                    ");
                    break;

                    case 3:
                    ch = String("The comfort zone is the great enemy to creativity; moving beyond it necessitates intuition, 
                    which in turn configures new perspectives and conquers fears.- Dan Stevens<br><br>
                    Today\'s challenge:<br><br>
                    Trust yourself and make snap decisions. We\'re contradicting ourselves, but there\'s a good reason. 
                    Just as there are people who thrive on snap decisions, others are more comfortable weighing all of 
                    the possible options several times, over and over again. Sometimes making a snap call is in order, 
                    just to get things moving. Doing so can help you kickstart your personal projects and teach you to trust your judgement. 
                    It\'ll also show you there\'s fallout to quick decisions as well as slow ones.");
                    break;

                    case 4:
                    ch = String("Comedians tend to find a comfort zone and stay there and do lamer versions of themselves for the rest of their career.- Chris Rock<br><br>
                    Today\'s challenge:<br><br>
                    Take your time making decisions. 
                    Sometimes slowing down is all it takes to make you uncomfortable—especially if speed and 
                    quick thinking are prized in your work or personal life. Slow down, 
                    observe what\'s going on, take your time to interpret what you see, and then intervene. 
                    Sometimes just defending your right to make an educated decision can push you out of your comfort zone. 
                    Think, don\'t just react.");
                    break;

                    case 5:
                    ch = String("I think when you get people who are really talented and you take them out of their comfort zone, you get a lot more out of them.- Gore Verbinski<br><br>
                    Today\'s challenge:<br><br>
                    Do it in small steps. It takes a lot of courage to break out of your comfort zone. 
                    You get the same benefits whether you go in with both feet as you do if you start slow, so don\'t be afraid to start slow. 
                    If you\'re socially anxious, don\'t assume you have to muster the courage to ask your crush on a date right away, 
                    just say hello to them and see where you can go from there. Identify your fears, and then face them step by step.");
                    break;

                    case 6:
                    ch = String("When you go out of your comfort zone and it works there's nothing more satisfying.- Kristen Wiig<br><br>
                    Today\'s challenge:<br><br>
                    Be aware of attachment to objects<br><br>
                    Notice your attachments to objects such as a cool sweater, a new gadget or any other thing that would make you feel bad if you lost it. 
                    What is the deep reason for being attached to them? Can you find the strength to let go of the attachment and give the object away?");
                    break;
                }

                document.write("<p>" + ch.big() + "</p>");
            </script>
            </div>
            <form>
                <label for="textarea-1">Post on Facebook:</label>
                <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea-1" id="textarea-1" >
                </textarea>
            </form>

            <input type="submit" value="Post to Facebook">
        </div><!-- /content -->
```

Comment: Have you checked your Javascript console?

Comment: i coded in aptana studio

Comment: and you tested this is some web browser I'm assuming. Which is how you decided that it wasn't working. All modern browsers have a Javascript console, check it and see what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript treats every new line as separate statement and You are using multiline string

so use `\` at each end of the line in string(..) to make it one string

I have edited and added `\` in this demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M9Wgw/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things. Like shadow said, you need to ensure the multiline strings are dealt with properly. Also in `case 0:` you don't need the curly brackets around the main clause. You have them right for the other cases.

I'm going to make a suggestion that might make it a bit easier. Hold the information you want in an array in an object:

```
obj = {

  0: [
    'day one',
    'this is what\'s happened',
    'we\'re separating up the text so that we keep the line lengths manageable'
  ],

  1: [
    'blah blah',
    'blah blah'
    ]

};
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
var n = new Date().getDay();
var info = obj[n].join('');
document.write("<p>" + info.big() + "</p>");
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions :D now I can do something else too :)